# Place output of while as a string

Tags: php

What would be the best practise in placing the results of a while function into a string.

For example :

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($select2)){
    echo "id:".$id."<br />";
    echo "Job Title: ".$title."<br />";
    echo "Email: ".$email."<br />";
}

$message = $row2;
```

This is what I've tried, but can't find the right way of going about it. Many thanks

Comment: There is no definite answer to this. There is no best way. It will often depend on what you are trying to do. Hence I'm close voting this question. Sometimes you want to echo sometimes you want to concatenate somwtimes you may want to build an array first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate it:

```
$message = '';

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($select2)){
    $message .= "id:".$id."<br />";
    $message .= "Job Title: ".$title."<br />";
    $message .= "Email: ".$email."<br />";
}

echo $message;
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai and everyone else for their quick solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use an array.

```
$message = "";
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($select2)){
   $message[] = "id:".$row2['id'];
   $message[] = "Job Title: ".$row2['title'];
   $message[] = "Email: ".$row2['email'];
}

echo implode('<br />', $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the string concat operator:

```
$message = "";
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($select2)){
   $message .= "id:".$id."<br />";
   $message .= "Job Title: ".$title."<br />";
   $message .= "Email: ".$email."<br />";
}

echo $message;
```